# Monitor ads showing on site by their URL

Tags: javascript, google-adsense, advertising

**Intro:** I use Ezoic to show ads on my site. It uses many ad exchanges such as Google Ad Exchange to real-time bid against my Adsense ad inventory, and the winner will be shown on ad placements.

**Problem:** Google Ad Exchange wins the bid most of the time, but there will be times when other ad exchanges win the bid. I want to block all ad exchanges' URLs/sources/scripts/whatever it is- From loading because Google AdExchange provides a feature to see what users are seeing and blocking unsuitable ads.

I'm looking for a way to monitor all loaded external URLs (ads' URLs) on my site so I can block ones coming from ad exchanges except Google.

I can't try to create any script since I'm no developer. Ezoic has a blocking control feature but it does not show ads that users are seeing, and it doesn't allow you to block a whole ad exchange.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Couple of things you can do. You can contact Ezoic directly and request that only Google exchange be allowed on your inventory. Or if they can't let you cherry pick exchanges, you can change your provider to something other than Ezoic. Or you can skip such intermediaries and plug into Google directly. The whole point of ad networks and such is that you can access multiple exchanges. If you only want one, try plugging into that one directly.